# Load specific environment with Laravel 5.1 Artisan CLI

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I'm currently trying to develop my own Artisan Scripts. And for that, I need to load another environment than only "local".

I've created 3 files : ".env.local", ".env.development", ".env.production" and during the deployment, I create a Symlink from .env.XXX to .env

That's working.

Now, with my Artisan in CLI-mode; I want to just call my method with that :

`php artisan --env=development myowncommand:exec`

... where "development" is my .env.**** file.

I should call other environments by :

`php artisan --env=local myowncommand:exec`

`php artisan --env=development myowncommand:exec`

`php artisan --env=production myowncommand:exec`

That doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong ? Any idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of a hack, but you can leverage loadEnvironmentFrom().  Copy the "artisan" file in the root directory to "artisan-local", "artisan-development", etc.

In the file, under the line:

`$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel');`

Add:

`$app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.local');`

Change '.env.local' as appropriate.